# MessageQueue.EndReceive occasionally throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

We are using `MessageQueue.EndReceive` to retrieve messages from a local MSMQ in a Windows service asynchronously.

Occasionally, the method fails with a `NullReferenceException`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.endreceive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not document this as a possible exception and a quick look at the source does not show where this could happen; the code appears to validate all references and would throw an `Argument*Exception` instead.

There is a knowledge base article *You receive an error message when you perform asynchronous receive operations on a Message Queuing dependent client* ([KB 816497](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816497)) that documents this as a .NET Framework 1.0|1.1 bug, suggesting it was fixed in subsequent versions. There are also [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126253/msmq-createcursor-nullreferenceexception) to problems with `Cursors`, which we don't use.

The solution presented is not directly related as the `AsyncResult` looks valid, and the suggested caching seems redundant. Conversely, the [`MessageQueue.EnableConnectionCache`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.msmq.programming/lGvxkihtKCM) looks inappropriate as the code does not modify the set of connected queues after startup.

Is there a documented resolution to this, or is the cause known and an established workaround available?

Comment: What is the total message? And have you checked that the `IAsyncResult` has not been collected yet as the article suggests?

Comment: The message sizes are small (~1k). The Queue only has a single outstanding BeginReceive at any time. I don't think that this is the reason, but will check again.

Comment: the `IAsyncResult` is valid and contains a valid `AsyncState` that we have defined.

Comment: I am occasionally seeing similar behavior where EndRecieve on a Socket type throws a NULL reference exception and the IAsyncResult looks valid (with a non-null AsyncState).